# MySQL Combine Query Results From Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Suppose I have two tables: shares and follows.  Currently, I have a query that returns the latest shares ordered by date, limited to 25 results.  What I would like to do is query from both follows and shares, returning the latest 25 results.  However, I'm unsure as to how to do this.

My query for the shares is like so:

```
select s.id, s.name, s.sharer, s.type from shares s where id = :id order by s.date desc limit 0,25
```

My query for the followers is like so:

```
select f.follower, f.following, f.type from followers f where f.following = :id order by f.date desc limit 0,25
```

How can I combine these so that if it selects from the followers table, it only takes the follower, following, and type and if it selects from the shares table, it only takes id, name, etc?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Are the two tables related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* that you're looking for a union...

```
    select id, name, sharer, type from (        
    (select s.id as id, 
            s.name as name, 
            s.sharer as sharer, 
            s.type as type, 
            s.date as date 
       from shares s 
       where id = :id order by s.date desc)
        UNION
    (select f.follower as id, 
            f.following as name, 
            f.following as sharer,
            f.type as type,
            f.date as date
        from followers f 
        where f.following = :id order by f.date desc)) 
        order by date desc limit 0,25;
```

You may need to adjust the alias as needed.

Comment: The two inner queries should be combined, resorted, and limited to the top twenty five.

Comment: if you are sure that there is no intersection between the results use UNION ALL. With this you will be able to improve query performance.